# Intermediate value theorem is the solution unique,

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Have the following

$f(x)=x^2 \exp(\sin(x))-\cos(x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$, I have shown the function is continuous and that there is at least one solution on the interval via using IVT, I know I have to find another solution in the interval such that $f(x)<0$, $f(x)>0$ and then $f(x)<0$, just wondering what is the best way to approach, Im sure there must be a more effective way than just to number crunch, could we consider MVT on the interval, many thanks in advance.

Comment: By "one solution," presumably you mean one solution to $f(x)=0$?  Pedantic, yes, but a function is not an equation.

Comment: Take the derivative.  You will get a positive impression.

Comment: Why do you think there is more than one solution to $f(x)=0$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas many thanks for the input.

Comment: The answer of @Simon Markett is much better than my comment, and I am not referring to my feeble pun. Sure, if you find the derivative, it is obvious that it is positive, end of story. But looking *directly* at the two functions is the "right" approach, derivative is mechanical. *Look* and then (if necessary) compute is much better than *compute* and then look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $x^2exp(sin(x))$ is *increasing*, the function $cos(x)$ is *decreasing* in your interval. Hence the combined functions is increasing on your interval. It starts with a value of $-1$ and goes up to $(\pi/2)^2e$. Therefore it has precisely *one* zero point.